# Addition on list slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

Why does the code

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
l[2:5] += [10]
print(l)
```

Give the output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7]
```

It is inserting the 10 in between, but I want to add 10 to indexes 2 to 4.

I also tried

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
l[2:5] += 10
print(l)
```

But it is showing an error saying int not iterable.
Shouldn't it automatically covert to `[10, 10, 10, 10]` and add to the required slice?

Comment: "but I want to add 10 to indexes 2 to 4." Well, that isnt how the Python list API works. " Shouldn't it automatically covert to [10,10,10,10] and add to the required slice?" No, why *should* it? Here is some relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range

Comment: You want to add 10 to the values at indexes 2 to 4?

Comment: try numpy if you want this kind of behavior

Comment: `arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])` then `arr[2:5] += 10` then it will give `array([ 0,  1, 12, 13, 14,  5,  6,  7])`

Comment: the `+` operator for python list stand s for concatenation so it is not suitable for element wise operation, for that you can use `numpy`

Comment: can you please post your desired output.

Answer (score 4):

Lists can be added like this:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Notice that the left list is extended by the right, not that the elements are added together.

The operator `+=` (as in `a += b`) is equivalent to `a = type(a).__iadd__(a, b)`. `__iadd__` is the in-place equivalent of `__add__`, which is regular `+`.

In your case, the expression `l[2:5] += [10]` becomes

```
l[2:5] = list.__iadd__(l[2:5], [10])
```

On the right hand side, the slice `l[2:5]` extracts a temporary object, which is modified in-place by extending it with the contents of `10`. On the left hand side, you replace elements `2:5` with the new, longer, list.

It should be pretty clear at this point why the scalar assignment fails entirely.

Remember that lists can hold anything, not just numbers, and must have reasonable behavior in those cases too. If you want to add something to the subset of a list, you have to go through each element individually:

```
for i in range(2, 5):
    l[i] *= 10
```

Numpy is probably a better way to do this if you are working with purely numerical data. Numpy arrays support exactly the sort of addition operator you are looking for:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(l)
>>> a[2:5] += 10
>>> a
array([  0,  1, 12, 13, 14,  5,  6,  7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

Example:

```
for index in range(2,5):
    l[index] += 10
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 12, 13, 14, 5, 6, 7]
```